# how do you reload a module in python version 3.3.2

Tags: python

whenever I try to reload a python module in python version 3.3.2 i get this error code

```
>>> import bigmeesh
>>> bob=bigmeesh.testmod()
this baby is happy
>>> imp.reload(bigmeesh)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    imp.reload(bigmeesh)
NameError: name 'imp' is not defined
```

I tried researching and still got no answers.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to `import imp` before you can use it, just as with any other module:

```
>>> import bigmeesh
>>> import imp
>>> imp.reload(bigmeesh)
```

---

Note that [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/imp.html) clearly says:

> Note: New programs should use `importlib` rather than this module.

However, in 3.3, `importlib` doesn't have a simple `reload` function; you'd have to build it yourself out of `importlib.machinery`. So, for 3.3, stick with `imp`. But in 3.4 and later which do have [`importlib.reload`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload), use that instead.

---

It's also worth noting that `reload` is often not what you want. For example, if you were expecting `bob` to change into an instance of the new version of `bigmeesh.testmod()`, it won't. But, on the other hand, if you were expecting it to not change at all, you might be surprised, because some of its behavior might depend on globals that *were* changed.

Comment: Thank you, it worked is there a book or something on the changes made in python 3.3.2?

Comment: @ChalleeCassandraSmith: As in between 3.3.1 and 3.3.2? Or 3.2 and 3.3? Or all the versions from 2.7 to 3.3? Whichever one you want, I don't know of any book, but the docs have an extensive [What's New in Python](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/) section.

Comment: @ChalleeCassandraSmith: But anyway, there isn't anything new here. Even in pre-1.0 versions of Python, you couldn't use functions from any module without importing that module, and the `imp` module has existed since Python 1.4.

Answer (score 10):

This is the modern way of reloading a module:

```
# Reload A Module
def modulereload(modulename):
    import importlib
    importlib.reload(modulename)
```

Just type `modulereload(MODULE_NAME)`, replacing `MODULE_NAME` with the name of the module you want to reload.

For example, `modulereload(math)` will reload the math function.