# dynamically update module using exec and compile in Python

Tags: python, compilation, exec, imp

I would like to dynamically import and update modules.  The more efficient way would likely be to use `importlib` and `imp.reload` [as suggested by abarnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500283/how-do-you-reload-a-module-in-python-version-3-3-2).  However another solution would be to use `exec` and `compile`.  I have a sample script below that demonstrates how a module stored in a string can be called and used on the fly.  However, when I call this module in function `test` (see below), it does not work, and is giving me an error message `global name 'FRUITS' is not defined`.  I need some fresh pairs of eyes to point me out why this does not work.  Thanks.

```
module_as_string = """ 
class FRUITS:
    APPLE = "his apple"
    PEAR = "her pear"
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
    def get_fruit(self):
        return FRUITS.APPLE
_class_name = foo """

def get_code_object():
    return compile(module_as_string, "<string>", "exec")

def test():
    exec(get_code_object())        
    a = eval("_class_name()")
    print(a.get_fruit())

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # below doesn't work
    test()

    # below works
    exec(get_code_object())
    a = eval("_class_name()")
    print(a.get_fruit())
```

-- 
Edit:
Let me know how I can improve this question if you think it is not worthy of asking. Don't just down vote. Thanks.

Comment: I did not downvote, but you say above "when I call this module in function test (see below), **it does not work**" (emphasis mine) you need to be specific about what is going wrong.

Comment: I didn't down-vote but one improvement to your question could be to explain why you want to do it like this even though you already admit it is an inferior solution compared to using `importlib`.  Also “it does not work” is not a very precise problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within function `test`, while FRUIT is a local variable, we do not have direct access to it.  To access  `FRUIT`, an additional container, `dict_obj` should be passed in to `exec`, which we can then use to access the executed classes from that container.  A working example is shown below.

```
def test():
    dict_obj = {}
    exec(get_code_object(),dict_obj)
    a = dict_obj["_class_name"]()
    print(a.get_fruit())
```