# When I install older version of scikit-learn in Google Colab, it still import the newest version

Tags: scikit-learn, google-colaboratory, uninstallation

I would like to use scikit-learn version 0.24.1 in Google Colab. First, I uninstall the current installed version (which is 0.24.2) by:

```
!pip uninstall scikit-learn -y
```

Then, I install version 0.24.1 by:

```
!pip install scikit-learn==0.24.1
```

However, when I import scitkit-learn, it is version `0.22.2.post1` which I think is the newest version not version 0.24.1.

If you have any idea how to solve it, please let me know.

Background:
I trained model by scikit-learn 0.24.1, and I want to use the same version to load trained model. Now, when I load trained model, I get warning that the version of scikit-learn is different from 0.24.1.

```
UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator _BinaryGaussianProcessClassifierLaplace from version 0.24.1 when using version 0.22.2.post1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to install the correct version *before* executing any import statements. When you `import sklearn` you're [loading the cached module](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) with the old version.

Alternatively you could patch things in the current notebook session by [reloading the module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18500299/3798897) via `imp` or `importlib`.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that version 0.24.2 was installed by another library. So, I have 2 versions of scikit-learn and I need to uninstall both.

Comment: Oh interesting; I wouldn't have expected that at all. Want to answer your own question, and I can remove this one?

Comment: Thank you. It is fine to keep your answer.